# ggbiplot - change the point size

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggbiplot

Does someone have an idea how to change the point size and still maintain the group colors in the code below?

Just adding the `geom_point(size = 8)` changes the colors of all the points to black.

Code:

```
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
g <- ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, 
              groups = wine.class, varname.size = 8, labels.size=10  , ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE)
g <- g + scale_color_discrete(name = '') #+  geom_point(size = 8)
g <- g + opts(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
              legend.position = 'top')
print(g)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a color aesthetic inside `geom_point` will keep the points colored by group. Also, I changed `opts` to `theme`, since `opts` has been deprecated.

```
ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, group=wine.class,
              varname.size = 8, labels.size=10, 
              ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = '') +  
  geom_point(aes(colour=wine.class), size = 8) +
  theme(legend.direction ='horizontal', 
        legend.position = 'top')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast respond and help

Comment: @eipi10, do you have idea how to bold the arrow and eclipses size and how to add repel in ggbiplot PCA ?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question while trying to make my points *smaller.* The answer by eipi10 does solve this problem nicely for making the points *larger* by simply plotting over the default points. While this is a simple solution that works, may I propose the following, which makes the default points invisible by setting the `alpha=0` and plotting the points in the aforementioned `geom_point` line:

```
ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, group=wine.class,
     varname.size = 8, labels.size=10, 
     ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE,
     alpha=0 #here's the change
) + 
scale_color_discrete(name = '') +  
geom_point(aes(colour=wine.class), size = 0.5) +  #set size of smaller points here
theme(legend.direction ='horizontal', 
    legend.position = 'top')
```